# VB.net save and load progress of background worker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

Is there a way for me to save and load my backgroundworker progress whenever i close or open my program?

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it like this;

In you main program create a 'Job Class' containing all the job parameters and outcome.

You then run the background worker, and pass the Job Class to the background worker.

On the backgroudworker you keep track of the progress in that class.

In your case you need to support job abortion, and pass outcome so far, back to the main program and save it with xml serialization, or some other method.

Then when you load the program for a second time, you need to load everything back in your job class again, and continue to run!

```
Public Class Job
     public JobProgress as integer
     public JobStillRunning as boolean
end class
```

Put everything in here that has to do with the job...

Then you call the job like;

```
BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(MyJob)
```

In your background process you can retrieve the class:

```
dim MyJob as Job = trycast(e.Argument, job)
```

On the progress update and finish you do the same, you just keep passing the class...

How to save a class to XML:

```
        Dim Serializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(Job))
        Using OutPutStream As System.IO.FileStream = New FileStream(OutPutFile, FileMode.CreateNew)
                  Serializer.Serialize(OutPutStream, MyJob)
        End Using
```

And how to load it again;

```
            Dim Serializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(Job))
            Using InputStream As System.IO.FileStream = New FileStream(AdminSettingsFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
                    MyJob = Serializer.Deserialize(InputStream)
            End Using
```

You can also compress and encrypt it with two lines of extra code. But I don't think you will be needing that...

Please note that not all types support serialization, for example, collections and sortedlists wont serialize. You need to convert them to flat array's.

Comment: i get the idea, but i don't know where to start with the code.

Comment: how to pass the backgroundworker progress to the class, for example my backgroundworker changes my textbox contents and controls a loop of arrays. i want to keep track of them.

Comment: how about the xml thing you said. i really wanna try saving and loading from it.